# react-native run-ios doesn't run the app, but building it from xcode works

Tags: react-native

I'm making a react-native app and have a problem.
When I run the command: react-native run-ios, the build succeeds, and simulator starts, but the app won't start and my console does not build js bundle.

[image]

but when I build the sourc /ios/[projectName].xcodeproj from XCode, It works fine.

Can anyone help figure out why and how to fix this?

Comment: Does the app at least install on the simulator when you try `react-native run-ios`?

Comment: If application installed successfully then please select the app to open.
Because sometime it may not open automatically.

Comment: Yeah, it is installed, and when I click the app, it crashes right after splash page. But when building in XCode, and do the same, the app works fine

Comment: solved, I don't know exactly, but it seemed to be a cocoapod problem.

Comment: did you find a solution to why it wont work using react-native run-ios

Comment: I face the same issue. How did you solve it? @Oza

Answer (score 1):

In my case, making sure I didn't have any simulators with the same name helped.

I recently updated to Xcode 10.2 and have simulators for iOS 12.1 and 12.2 but they have the same name in **Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulators**.

**UPDATE**: You can specify the iOS version for the simulator
`react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 6s (10.2)'` and it will attempt to find the correct simulator if there are multiple found.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19069#issuecomment-385545599

---

**OR** rename your simulators in xcode to whatever you want

[image: iPhone X iOS 12.1 simulator]

[image: iPhone X iOS 12.2 simulator]

Right click and rename one of them so the names are unique, then `react-native run-ios` started working.

[image: Rename simulator]

[image: Updated simulator name]

**Environment:**
Xcode: 10.2.1
React Native: 0.59.9